# Update all items in SharePoint list daily with SPD 2013 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, updatelistitems

There may be several solutions to this (common) problem, but I do not seem to find one that works, or they are too complicated.

I have a list with a calculated column "Status" that returns a single line of text based on a calculated column "DateDiff", which calculates the difference between a date column "ExpiryDate" and hyperlink column "Today". The Today column is based on a workflow created in SPD 2013, where the date is updated daily:

[image: workflow-update-TodayColumn]

However, this only seems to update the first item in the list. Is there a way to create a loop for all items in the list to be updated daily? I have about 250 items in the list.

Comment: Why do you need the difference in a field?  What happens when you google "sharepoint 2013 workflow loop through list items"? Don't you get many, many links to tutorials? I do.

Comment: Hi @teylyn, I found many links and tutorials, but the few that I've tried did not work or requires quite some database backend skills. I have tried to apply the solution from [Wes] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39361021/using-sharepoint-designer-loops-to-update-a-field-in-a-list-when-the-field-in-an), but it still only updates the first item. I think I may have an error somewhere in my workflow.

Comment: Yeah, all you need is in these tutorials. If you have an error in your workflow, you need to check and double check each step. We cannot help with that, unfortunately.